# Google Maps Latitude Longitude não encontra endereço, mas existe no Google Maps

Tags: google, maps

Estou utilizando a ferramenta de busca do CEP dos Correios. Como exemplo: estou buscando pelo cep: 04291-020 o retorno é: Rua Muller Carioba. Veja que há 2 letras L no nome.
Colocando esse mesmo endereço na URL do Google para buscar as coordenadas:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Rua Muller Carioba, 100, Jardim da Saude Sao Paulo SP
```

Temos o seguinte resultado:

```
   {
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Agora, se simplesmente removermos um dos dois L do nome, o resultado vem corretamente. Portanto a minha dúvida é: Como fazer com que essa busca de LAT/LNG funcione da mesma forma que o Google Maps? Pois no Google Maps ele encontra seja com 1 L ou com 2 L.

Comment: qual o tipo de aplicação está sendo utilizado? conforme seu relato testei no navegador no link [rua muller carioba](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Rua%20muller%20carioba) e obtive o resultado normalmente, possívelmente sua aplicação não deve estar passando corretamente o parametro da busca, com as informações que você postou não fica claro o suficiente, peço que edite a pergunta e coloque mais informações e treços do código.

Comment: Ok, questao editada.

Answer (score 0):

Colocando como pesquisa no google maps "Rua Muller Carioba, 100, Jardim da Saude Sao Paulo SP", nada foi encontrado.
Colocando a mesma pesquisa, sem o número, encontrou!

Ainda de qualquer maneira, sua URL tem um erro: espaços!

Quando você realiza uma solicitação via URL com parâmetros (chamada de [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)), você deve substituir os espaços por `%20` ou `+`, para que o navegador entenda a sua solicitação.

Portanto, se você executar a query abaixo: (já removendo o número 100, visto que com o número 100, nem o próprio google maps encontrou)

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Rua+Muller+Carioba+Jardim+da+Saude+Sao+Paulo+SP
```

você terá o retorno esperado!

Comment: Tudo bem amigo, eu entendo a questão dos espaços, o que no caso não influencia no resultado. Entretanto eu preciso que o endereço tenha o número da residência para ter a precisão na LAT/LNG.

Answer (score 0):

O problema de consumir esse método da *API* do **google.maps**, é que a mesma tem um limite de requisições diárias, neste caso, você tem que forçar a requisição de forma recursiva.
Ou seja, sempre que fizer isso e retornar o erro `"ZERO_RESULTS`, você refaça a consulta.
Claramente via *Cliente Side*

Abaixo um exemplo de como pode fazer isso em `Javascript`:

Observe que caso de falha na operação, a mesma vai setar um tempo de 3 segundos e refazer, forçando o método(nativo da *API*) Geocoder a buscar o endereço via latitude e longitude.

```
function getEndereco(lat, long, callback) {
    try {
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        let LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long)
        geocoder.geocode({ 'location': LatLng }, function (results, status) {
            let endereco = "Tente Novamente"
            if (status === 'OK') {
                if (results[1]) {
                    endereco = results[0].formatted_address
                    console.log("OK: " + endereco + " - Lat: " + lat + " - Lng: " + long);
                }
            }
            else if (status == 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
                clearTimeout(function () {
                    getEndereco1(lat, long, callback)
                })
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    getEndereco1(lat, long, callback)
                }, 3000)
                console.log("status: " + status);
            }
            callback(endereco);
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Erro na Função 'getEndereco' mensagem do erro: " + err.message);
    }
}
```